# The name 'CrossMedia' does not exist in the current context C# error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, media

I am writing code for a media plug-in in Xamarin Studio, and apparently I have the following error when I try to build the app:

"The name 'CrossMedia' does not exist in the current context"

I have been trying to find a fix for the problem. Below, is the code.

```
using System;
using Relate.Model;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using System.IO;

namespace Relate.Views
{

    public partial class EditMemberPage : ContentPage
    {
        public EditMemberPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void TakeaPhoto_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                // Supply media options for saving our photo after it's taken.
                var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Receipts",
                    Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.jpg"
                };

                // Take a photo of the business receipt.
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(mediaOptions);
            }

            if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
            {
                // Supply media options for saving our video after it's taken.
                var mediaOptions = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {
                    Directory = "Videos",
                    Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.mp4"
                };

                // Record a video
                var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(mediaOptions);
            }

            // Select a photo. 
            if (CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
            {
                var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
            }

            // Select a video. 
            if (CrossMedia.Current.IsPickVideoSupported)
            {
                var video = await CrossMedia.Current.PickVideoAsync();
            }
        }

        async void SaveButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var famMemberItem = (FamMember)BindingContext;
            await App.Database.SaveFamMemberAsync(famMemberItem);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you `using` the namespace where `CrossMedia` exists?

Comment: ...If `using` doesn't helped, please install this package from nuget.

Comment: @GraceFeng Which package?

Comment: @Stephane, [Media Plugin for Xamarin and Windows](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin).

Answer (score 2):

Add `using Plugin.Media;` to the start of your file

Comment: I did. I get an error stating that "The type or namespace 'Plugin' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: Adding that line of code to the start of the file helped. I was able to build the app by adding an assembly reference of the Plugin Media to the project class library. However, whenever I try to take a photo with the Android emulator, I get "Camera error. Can't access the camera."

Comment: Is your Android emulator set up with a camera? If not then you won't be able to access it.

Comment: You also need to add the NuGet package to every project in your app, so the PCL and whichever out of Droid, iOS and UWP that you have. You shouldn't add an assembly reference, just use the NuGet package

Comment: I added a NuGet Package Extension already but I still have a problem with the camera. The emulator has a screenshot option.

Answer (score 1):

Try initialize the plugin first before using it as said in its documentation.

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question now but I had the same problem having installed the package using the NuGet Package Manager CLI in VS2017 with:

```
Install-Package Xam.Plugin.Media
```

It seemed as though installation was not an issue but I was wrong. What I didn't realise is that it only installed it for the Android project and not for all projects. To do this you have to right click on the **Solution** at the top and select `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution`. Click on the `Xam.Plugin.Media` package and in an adjacent pane it will tell you whether you have it installed for all the projects in the solution with check boxes. If you have any gaps, you can then check the boxes and hit `Install` to complete the setup. This is mine after I corrected the issue:

[image: Screenshot of NuGet for the solution]